# Errors on memoir.cls after updating TexStudio and MikTex

Tags: latex, miktex, texstudio

I have TexStudio and MikTex to edit Latex files on my PC. After updating both of them to the versions 4.0.3 and 4.4, respectively, the compilation started to show a lot of errors on the memoir.cls file:

[image: Errors on memoir.cls]

When I try to compile a simpler file that doesn't use memoir.cls it works fine. I've already tried downgrade and reinstalling both.

Minimal Reproducible Example

```
\documentclass[msc]{ppgccufmg}


\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

Class ppgccufmg: https://github.com/verlab/ppgccufmg

If you want me to send anything else to help diagnose just let me know.

Comment: please add a [mre] to your question and show your complete .log file (not just the butchered result after texstudio parses it and leaves out all the useful information)

Comment: Done. I added the minimal reproducible example and the class it uses.

Comment: The problem is the `\RequirePackage{etextools}` in l. 40 of the class file. Without it the example works fine

Comment: narrowing the problem further down, it seems to be the `etex` package which is loaded by etextools. Minimal non-working example: `\RequirePackage{etex}
\documentclass{memoir}
\begin{document}
ggg
\end{document}`